# Importing missing glyphs in font

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I'm using a title font which has very few characters, and I need '+' and '=' for a given title, which are missing. Using `fontspec`, is it possible to import only these two missing glyphs from another font?

**Note:** it *is* a very similar question to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font), but I'd like to know if it can be done easily with `fontspec`.

Comment: Why not use math mode e.g. `$1+1=2$`?

Comment: That is a good idea, but my title font is scaled (huge is not big enough for my needs), so the math font doesn't scale the same.

Comment: Switch to another font for the two glyphs.

Comment: @Ulrike: that would work too, but I wanted to know if there was a cleaner way (just in case).

Comment: The clean way is to use a better font. All other solutions involve a font switch which you can do in various ways (commands, \XeTeXinterclass) but still is a font switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the symbols are used only in a few cases, the most efficient solution is to define `\newcommand{\biggerplus}{{\myplusfont +}}`, where `\myplusfont` is the declaration for choosing the substitute font.

If you *really* need to use directly `+` and `=`, then I suggest

```
\newfontfamily{\mytitlefont}{Some Font}
\newcommand{\choosetitlefont}{\mytitlefont\mytitlefonttrue}
\newif\ifmytitlefont
\let\pluschar=+
\catcode`+=\active
\protected\def+{\ifmytitlefont{\myplusfont\pluschar}\else\pluschar\fi}
\let\equalschar==
\catcode`==\active
\protected\def={\ifmytitlefont{\myplusfont\equalschar}\else\equalschar\fi}
```

Instead of calling `\mytitlefont` for typesetting the titles, you'll call `\choosetitlefont`.

Solutions with `\XeTeXintercharclass` would avoid activating the characters, but will have the conditional anyway.