# Half Brackets Not Showing in XeLaTeX

Tags: symbols, xetex, unicode

I have a XeLaTeX document with lower half brackets `⸤⸥` (U+2E24,U+2E25) and upper half brackets `⸢⸣` (U+2E22,U+2E23). In the log file I get the complaint like `Missing character: There is no ⸤ in font...` when I use Gentium or FreeSerif. However, in other contexts (Gnome Terminal, LibreOffice) these characters show up in those fonts. How can I get these characters to appear in my document?

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{FreeSerif}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{} These are ⸤lower half-brackets⸥. These are ⸢upper half-brackets⸣.
It seems that other symbols work—such as ê.
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Relevant portion of the log file:

```
Missing character: There is no ⸤ in font Free Serif/ICU:mapping=tex-text,!
Missing character: There is no ⸥ in font Free Serif/ICU:mapping=tex-text,!
Missing character: There is no ⸢ in font Free Serif/ICU:mapping=tex-text,!
Missing character: There is no ⸣ in font Free Serif/ICU:mapping=tex-text,!
```

Comment: How do you load the fonts? Are you sure they are also used in math mode? A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would help.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov I am not using math mode...is that the problem? I added the MWE you requested.

Comment: The other contexts probably use some fall-back font; specifically the symbols are available in DejaVu Sans.

Comment: @Caramdir that is an incredibly helpful comment! When I used DejaVu Sans, everything showed. I had no idea that applications used that as a fallback font. Of course, I don't actually want to typeset the document in DejaVu Sans...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not to hijack Caramdir's answer, but only to show a simpler solution, from the point of view of user input (it's equivalent from the TeXnical point of view):

```
\newfontfamily\fallbackfont{DejaVu Sans} % or any other font having the glyphs

\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{⸤}{{\fallbackfont ⸤}}
\newunicodechar{⸥}{{\fallbackfont ⸥}}
\newunicodechar{⸢}{{\fallbackfont ⸢}}
\newunicodechar{⸣}{{\fallbackfont ⸣}}
```

Comment: Well, this is clearly an easier solution. I always forget about `newunicodechar`...

Comment: @Caramdir Curiously, I don't. :)

Answer (score 7):

The following is adapted from [Importing missing glyphs in font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25519/importing-missing-glyphs-in-font). It makes the `⸤⸥⸢⸣` symbols use DejaVu Sans. I'm not particularly happy about how it looks since DejaVu Sans doesn't mix well with Gentium. Maybe you can find a better fall-back font (though few text fonts seem to contain these symbols).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Gentium}

\newfontfamily\fallbackfont{DejaVu Sans}
\let\swbrackchar=⸤
\catcode`⸤=\active
\protected\def⸤{{\fallbackfont\swbrackchar}}
\let\sebrackchar=⸥
\catcode`⸥=\active
\protected\def⸥{{\fallbackfont\sebrackchar}}
\let\nwbrackchar=⸢
\catcode`⸢=\active
\protected\def⸢{{\fallbackfont\nwbrackchar}}
\let\nebrackchar=⸣
\catcode`⸣=\active
\protected\def⸣{{\fallbackfont\nebrackchar}}

\begin{document}
These are ⸤lower half-brackets⸥. These are ⸢upper half-brackets⸣.
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

I'd be interested to know whether there is a mechanism to specify a global fall-back font, but that should be a separate question.

(Btw, `\paragraph{...}` is a sectioning command and isn't needed to start a paragraph.)